# How to implement timer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, timer, countdown, countdowntimer

I wish to implement timer in python, but could not find any useful articles on that.
My main aim is to implement the following logic:

```
`timer -> 60 seconds to zero
     #do stuff
     if the user selects to manually reset the timer -> start the time loop again
     if user exits -> exit the time loop
 reset the timer and again do above steps`
```

Am looking for articles / information of the syntax to implement the above logic.

Comment: What environment are you working in? Does the user interact with your program via terminal, a GUI, or a browser?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154568/postpone-code-for-later-execution-in-python-like-settimeout-in-javascript

Comment: Use `time.tme()` ?

Comment: @tiwo Am using terminal at the moment but would upgrade it in flask to use it in browser. So, for now i wish to implement it in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it in your /usr/bin/stopwatch and give appropriate permission (chmod +x script)

```
eg: sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/stopwatch
```

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time


if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Needs seconds as argument, Eg: stopwatch 10")
else:
    seconds = sys.argv[1]
    for i in range(int(seconds), 0, -1):
        print(str(" "*50), end='\r')
        print(str(i), end='\r')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
    print("Time over {}".format(seconds))
```

Usage

```
stopwatch 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually to develop timers in a multithreading enviroment i use the stopit package.
You can define a timer -> create a function that call .cancel() on the timer in case the user press cancel button -> catch the timeout exception to restart the timer.