# How to timeout a fuction in python

Tags: python

I am calling a function named as `func` for each sentence in my corpus as follows in python.

```
count =0    
for sentence in sentences:
   count += 1
   results.append(func(sentence))
```

I want to pass the sentences that takes too long to process by using timeout (e.g., timeout after 30 seconds and print the sentence number).

I tried to use the solution mentioned in: [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call) and timeout-decorator library as well.

However, both of the solutions returned me the same error mentioned below.

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

AttributeError: module 'signal' has no attribute 'SIGALRM'
```

Is there a way to perform timeout in python 3? Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postpone code for later execution in python (like setTimeout in javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154568/postpone-code-for-later-execution-in-python-like-settimeout-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signal package is part of UNIX/Linux package and needs to be installed.
If you are on windows check this out 
https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/issues/7

Comment: If it answered your question, can you please click the tick mark on the left side and accept it as answer

Comment: If you are on windows this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420422/python-windows-equivalent-of-sigalrm